# How to configure ReSharper 8's full code cleanup to treat automatic properties as fields instead of methods?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ide, resharper

ReSharper's cleanup code for C# puts fields at the top, and methods after them, which I find great.

However it's being too technical for me with putting automatic properties in the method sections (so they get mingled with other stuff). As far as I care if they're automatic properties (and not ones with body) -- they're fields to me.

Is there any way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to <kbd>Resharper</kbd>-><kbd>Options</kbd>-><kbd>C#</kbd>-><kbd>Formatting Style</kbd>-><kbd>Type Members Layout</kbd> and change the layout XML there.

The layout XML isn't very well documented. but here are some blog posts that describe how to set it up:

- [Code Cleanup Usage Scenatio's Reordering Type Membets](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Cleanup__Usage_Scenarios__Reordering_Type_Members.html)
- [In depth look at customizing type layout with Resharper](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/01/04/in-depth-look-at-customizing-type-layout-with-resharper/)

Properties should be matched as their own distinct group and this is working for my version of Resharper (8.1). It is possible your layout has been overwritten or changed from the default.

My configuration is using the formatting which is enforced by StyleCop.

Comment: If you want us to help fix the ordering, please paste the layout XML from your resharper configuration.

Comment: I actually do have the default. I'd love to get yours tho; that is if you don't mind posting it.

Comment: This is the one set by StyleCop: http://stylecop.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Project/Src/AddIns/ReSharper800/Resources/ReorderingPatterns.xml